# does the inverse of this linear transformation exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

$e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$
I have two linear transformation $T_1$ and $T_2$ as below:
$T_1$: rotation ccw $30^o$. so I can show it as $A_1=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\frac{-1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\end{bmatrix}$
$T_2$: reflection about y=-x. so I can show it as $A_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$
No I am asked to show what $(T_2oT_1)^{-1}$ is. But I have a problem.
I found $T_2oT_1 =\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-1}{2}\\\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\end{bmatrix} $ for $e_1.$
How am I supposed to take the inverse of this 2*1 matrix, since it is not an square matrix. should I answer, this transformation does not exist?

Comment: That is $T_{2}T_{1}e_{1}$, not $T_{2}T_{1}$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are linear isomorphisms: $T_1^{-1}$ is the rotation by 30$^\circ$ in the other direction and $T_2^{-1}=T_2$.

Hence
$$(T_2\circ T_1)^{-1}=T_1^{-1}\circ T_2^{-1}=T_1^{-1}\circ T_2$$

(that can be represented by a $2\times 2$ matrix).

In fact compositions of rotations and reflections [behave very well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_and_reflections_in_two_dimensions) – in your case it will be just a reflection about another axis.